# Complexity of integer programming with added predicates

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity, integer-programming

A classical theorem in Integer Programming by Lenstra says that any integer system
$$A x \le b$$ 
can be solved in polynomial time, where $A \in \mathbb{Z}^{m \times n}, x \in \mathbb{Z}^n, b \in \mathbb{Z}^m$. Here we fix the dimension $n$ of the variables to be solved over (it would be NP-complete to solve for $n$ arbitrary).

Viewed under the the lense of logic/computational complexity, this theorem says that any *existential* statement
$$ \exists x \in \mathbb{Z}^n : \Phi(x)$$
can be decided in polynomial time, where $\Phi$ is a formula in Presburger arithmetic.

By the work of Semenov, we also know that Presburger arithmetic with added precidates, such as "x is a power of 2", or "x is a Fibonacci number" is *decidable*.

**Question**: For $n$ fixed, can we decide in polynomial time sentences of the form
$$\exists x \in \mathbb{Z}^n : \Psi(x)$$
where $\Psi(x)$ is a Presburger formula, augmented with some the Fibonacci (or Power of 2) predicates?

**Example**: Does the following system have a solution?

$$ \begin{cases} 3x_1 + 2x_2 \le 1000 \\ 17x_2 - x_1 \le 5 \\ 2x_1 + 5x_2 \quad \text{is a power of 2} \end{cases} $$

Comment: Are you restricting to $x_i>0$?

Comment: it looks very unlikely to me...

Comment: Yes we can restrict to positive variables. I don't think it will change much.

Comment: I'm sure you know (but I will also mention for the sake of completeness) that SMT solvers can do this sort of thing in practice.

Comment: switching to positive variables is a linear change of variables, you double the number of them, which is OK in this setting.

Comment: What do you do if there is no solution?

Comment: @joro: I would like to have a procedure to decide if there is a solution or not. More specifically, I am interested in the complexity of such a procedure.

Comment: Do I miss something? It's well known that deciding propositions in Presberger arithmetic takes double-exponential time. Integer programming would seem to be worse rather than better than a mere decision algorithm, which could be seen as a solver whose result was constrained to be in the set {0,1}.

Comment: @SteveHuntsman 'SMT solvers can do this sort of thing in practice' could you explain that?

Comment: @Turbo The simplest way to have an SMT solver work on this is to have a literal for each power of two in a reasonable range (note this is imposing bounds) and then just do its thing. I’m not sure if there is a better way to do things offhand. A good place to start after https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories is http://www.decision-procedures.org